# Opening multiple split windows with GNU screen with single bash script

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I would like to create a bash script to automatically open a screen window with 4 sessions running predetermined commands. I'd like to open htop and slurm on the top two frames, squidview in the middle large frame and a blank terminal on the bottom large frame. Is this possible to set up with a single bash script?

Comment: Here is a Q&A that addresses this:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381435/ubuntu-16-04-bash-can-i-open-two-interactive-terminal-windows-in-a-single-scri/381528#381528

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This does something like you desire:

```
$ cat my_screenrc
screen top 
split
focus down
screen vmstat 1
split
focus down
screen
focus bottom
$ screen -c my_screenrc
```

`screen` appears to be more directed toward screen flipping than multiple panels and the documentation is pretty arcane.